# How to create an object with a variable as it's name?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is what I want, from this array:

```
array1 = [{name: "a", value: 1, size: 2},{name: "a", value: 2, size: 3},{name: "b", value: 1 ,size: 4}];
```

to create an array like this:

```
array2 = [{ "a", {value: 1, size: 2},{value: 2, size: 3}},{ "b",{value: 1 ,size: 4}}]
```

Basically to create an array containing objects that are "grouped" objects based on their name.
I tried to do it with a foreach loop and a function like so:

```
var array1 = [{name: "a", value: 1, size: 2},{name: "a", value: 2, size: 3},{name: "b", value: 1 ,size: 4}];
var array2;
function make(element){
    array2['element[0]'] = [element[1], element[2]];
};
array1.forEach(make(this));
```

But I got an error: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'element[0]' of undefined".
I tried using the Object.defineProperty method but couldn't manage to implement it.
How can I get from array1 to array2 ??

**I searched for similar questions on this subject but couldn't find a specific answer to my question.

Comment: You don't give *array2* a value so your attempting to access properties of *undefined*. Also, you probably meant `array2[element[0]]` and `{"a", {...}}` is not a valid object literal. But those are just syntax errors, they won't fix the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems is that you're passing the return value of `make(this)` as the callback for `.forEach()`, which is `undefined`; this invocation is the right one:

```
array1.forEach(make);
```

Second, you're not initialising `array2` properly as an object.

```
var array2 = {};
```

Third, each element is an object and not an array so you should reference the fields by name. Lastly, if you want to group by name, what you do in each iteration depends on whether you've seen the name before:

```
function make(element)
{
    if (!array2[element.name]) {
      array2[element.name] = [];
    }
    array2[element.name].push({value: element.value, size: element.size});
};
```

```js
var array1 = [{name: "a", value: 1, size: 2},{name: "a", value: 2, size: 3},{name: "b", value: 1 ,size: 4}];
var array2 = {};
function make(element)
    {
        if (!array2[element.name]) {
          array2[element.name] = [];
        }
        array2[element.name].push({value: element.value, size: element.size});
    };
array1.forEach(make);
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly straightforward solution:

```js
var array1 = [{name: "a", value: 1, size: 2}, {name: "a", value: 2, size: 3}, {name: "b", value: 1 ,size: 4}];

function collect(arr) {
  var values = {};
  arr.forEach(function (el) {
    if (!values[el.name]) { values[el.name] = []; }
    values[el.name].push({ value: el.value, size: el.size });
  });
  return Object.keys(values).map(function (key) {
    var o = {};
    o[key] = values[key];
    return o;
  });
}

var array2 = collect(array1);

console.log(array2);
document.write(JSON.stringify(array2));
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the OP wanted. I think it's `[{ "a": [{value: 1, size: 2},{value: 2, size: 3}]},{ "b":[{value: 1 ,size: 4}]}]` but I might be wrong about that.

Comment: @RobG Alright, fixed to produce what the OP *probably* wanted.